# Can you calculate e if d and φ(n)

Tags: security, rsa, cryptojs

Obviously d can be found from e and φ(n) but can e be right if d is given and φ(n) is given by putting in the values in the algorithm

Comment: Your question is not clear, but if you have e **or** d and φ(n) then finding the other value is easy.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.